# Printing a string in reverse using a linked list

Tags: c, list, debugging, data-structures

I build a program that takes a string from a command line and use a linked list to print it in reverse.

I am currently debugging my program and I am just completely stuck. I have a feeling most are memory related.

```
/*

Takes a string from the command line.  
Makes a linked-list out of it in reverse order.  
Traverse it to construct a string in reverse.  
Clean up (release memory).
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct st_CharNode 
{
char theChar;
struct st_CharNode *next;
} CharNode;


void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer );


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
char *stringBuffer;

//  Check number of user supplied arguments.  
if( argc != 2 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s string.  This reverses the string "
             "given on the command line\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

// Copy the argument so we can make changes to it
stringBuffer = malloc( strlen(argv[1]) );
strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );

// Reverse the string
reverseIt( stringBuffer );

// Print the reversed string
printf( "the reversed string is '%s'\n", *stringBuffer );

return 0;
}


// Build a linked list backwards, then traverse it.

void reverseIt( char *stringbuffer )
{
CharNode *head, *node;
char *scan, *stop;

// initialize local vars
head = node = NULL;

// find the start and end of the string so we can walk it
scan = stringbuffer;
stop = stringbuffer + strlen(stringbuffer) + 1;

// walk the string
while (scan < stop)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        head->theChar = *scan;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node = malloc( sizeof(CharNode*) );
        node->theChar = *scan;
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    scan++;
}

// Re-point to the buffer so we can drop the characters
scan = stringbuffer;

//  Traverse the nodes and add them to the string
while( head != NULL )
{
    *scan = head->theChar;
    free( head );
    node = head->next;
    head = node;
    scan++;
}
// Release head
free( head );   
}
```

Comment: "I am just completely stuck". That's not an adequate description of the problem. Please state the inputs, the expected behaviour, the actual behaviour, what you have done to debug it yourself and what your specific question is ("debug it for me" is not a specific question).

Comment: Just referring to the title: why would someone do *that*? Iterate through the string from the end to the beginning and copy the characters to a newly allocated buffer of the same size. I've seen a lot of "abuses" of the concept of linked lists, but this seems to be one of the "very best".

Comment: You can just use the linked list as a stack. When you create a new element, set it's next pointer to the first element structure, and after you set the first element pointer to the new element structure. After the user stopped typing, you just go through the list from the first pointer , because it is already revetsed now.

Comment: @LászlóKardinál that's true, but i still keep wondering: why use a linked list *at all*? Applied waste of resources?

Comment: Learning about linked lists will be useful when you need to design more advanced data structures. You probably won't implement any other linked list in your life, because there will be existing libraries for that, but when you will meet a similar problem, you will need the logic of these structures.

Answer (score 0):

An error I've seen is that you are using strcpy like this:

```
strcpy( argv[1], stringBuffer );
```

which copies the value of stringBuffer into argv[1], you should do it the other way around, like this:

```
strcpy( stringBuffer, argv[1]);
```

see the man page of strcpy for more information: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy